# BitMEX API cant connect due to "Exception thrown: 'System.Net.WebException' in System.dll"

Tags: c#, bitmex

I am trying to make a bot for BitMEX using the official api connector provided by bitmex

https://github.com/BitMEX/api-connectors

But when trying to connect, it says in the output "Exception thrown: 'System.Net.WebException' in System.dll"

Does anyone know how to fix this

Comment: Welcome to the site.  Please post the code where you're having trouble

Comment: did you find a fix for this mate?